# My app Crash due to some error in my node.js backend code which post the accesoies and slug into databse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Its my node.js backend code which put the accesory and slug into the database I dont know why my app crash

```
const express=require('express');
const Category = require("../models/Category");
const slugify=require('slugify');
const router=express.Router;



router.post('/addcategory',(req,res)=>{

 const categoryObj={
    name:req.body.name,
    slug:slugify(req.body.name)
 }

 if(req.body.parentId){
    
 categoryObj.parentId=req.body.parentId;

}

const cat=new Category(categoryObj);

cat.save((error,Category)=>{
    if(error) return res.status(400).json({error});
    if(Category){
        return res.status(201).json({Category});
    }
})




});

module.exports=router;
```

Its My Model schema code of mongodb I added it for your assistent

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { schema } = require('./User');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const CategorySchema=new Schema({

name:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true
},
slug:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    unique:true
},
parentId:{
    type:String
}






});
const Category=mongoose.model('Category',CategorySchema);
module.exports=Category;
```

Its my index.js code

```
const connectToMongo=require('./db');
var cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express')

connectToMongo();
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
const port = 5000


app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/authent',require('./routes/authent'))
app.use('/api/category1',require('./routes/category'))


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`iNoteBook Backend listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The error thro by the terminal is

C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\cinemaapp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:513
this.stack.push(layer);
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
at Function.route (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\cinemaapp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:513:14)
at Function.proto. [as post] (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\cinemaapp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:520:22)
at Object. (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\cinemaapp\backend\routes\category.js:8:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\cinemaapp\backend\index.js:13:26)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Edit your post to include this file's code: `backend\routes\category.js`

Comment: could you elaborate please do you want me to add this path into my router.post('here')

Comment: `require` your custom module must go with the entire module's name, e.g, `require("../models/Category.js");` instead of `require("../models/Category");`. Check [require Module](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nodejs-require-module/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating a router properly, you need to *call* `express.Router`:

```
const router = express.Router();
```